# Navigate Among The Custom Tabs Dynamically In Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I was trying to create custom tabs and each one have their own sections. Tabs and sections are dynamically coming from server.
Here is the link [Tabs with html](http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Tabs-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/) and I need same functionality with ionic 2 and want to **alive element in DOM** and I can't used `*ngIf` directive.

Here is what I have right now:

1.This is Json data

```
this.filterData=[
  {"key":"Budget","value":["10-100000"],"type":"bar","labelid":"17"},
  {"key":"Parking Capacity","value":["0-100","101-250",">251"],"type":"checkbox","labelid":"12"},
  {"key":"Venue","value":["Indoor","Outdoor","Indoor\/Outdoor"],"type":"checkbox","labelid":"3"},
  {"key":"No.of Rooms","value":["0-10","11-30",">31 "],"type":"checkbox","labelid":"15"},
  {"key":"Max.Capacity","value":["0-100"],"type":"bar","labelid":"1"},
  {"key":"Function Type","value":["Marriage","Engagement","Anniversary","Birthday","Cocktail","Corporate","Party"],"type":"checkbox","labelid":"11"}];
```

2.**Left section: i have created the tabs**

**Right section: i have created div for each tabs**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-4 class="one">
        <ion-row *ngFor="let type of filterData">{{type.key}}</ion-row>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col col-8 > 
          <ion-item *ngFor="let function of filterData">
            <div>{{function.labelid}}</div>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

and it is look like this
[image]

i want to switch among this tabs and show corresponding div section.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: `angular` and `angularjs` both tags are different tags. `angular` tag is strictly for angular 2/4 where as `angularjs` is for angular 1.x. So please remove one of the tag from your question accordingly.

Comment: i have removed the tag

Comment: sounds like [segments](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/)

Comment: i have tried the segments but not able to achieve with that . Do you have any clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, You can use **[Segment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#segment)** to build a navigation button group.

And for showing corresponding div sections, just use a **ngSwitch** to control showing them based on selected segment value.

---

Since you want to keep the elements after switch, `ngSwitch` will remove hidden elements as the same with `ngIf`, you can use **hidden** to control showing corresponding div sections. (demo updated)

Refer sample **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vqh9kz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**.

Comment: I have tried to used the segment to achieve this but on switching it removes the element from the DOM and need to keep alive element in DOM while user switch to another div section

Comment: @SurajBahadur this is not about segment, it's ngSwitch that removes your elements, you can simply use show/hidden to achieve what you want.

Comment: It is working great with static div section but number of div creation are not fixed. i have run the *ngFor to creatde div section as we created left section but having problem with " [hidden]="selectedSegment !== 'a1'"  " as here we are assign the a1 but i have assign it dynamically but it not working . can you please help me once more . A lot's of thank you ..YOUR ARE SAVIOUR

Comment: @SurajBahadur see udpated demo.

Comment: WOW, YOU ARE TRUE SAVIOUR, YOU HAVE SAVED MY LIFE. A LOT'S OF THANK YOU FROM BOTTOM OF MY HEART. YOU ARE GREAT.LOVE U